# Find if key contains value in a map and return a boolean

Tags: groovy, collections

I have a map within an object in Groovy. The map has keys made from long strings, I want to see if a key in my map contains a certain value within the string and return a boolean.

For example if my map key is 'X1234_RANDOM_STRING', if my parameter is X1234 I want to look in my map and see if the a key with that value exists and return true of false.

Currently I am using .find however this doesn't return a boolean, I thought I could use .containsKey() but this won't work when my parameter may only contain a portion of the string.

```
map.find {
   it.key.toString().contains(code)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need boolean output, use `collect` instead of `find`.

Here you go:

```
def code = 'X1234'
def map = [X1234_RANDOM_STRING: 1]
print map.collect {    it.key.toString().contains(code) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following (very close to your attempt):

```
def map = ['X1234_RANDOM_STRING': 5150]
def code = 'X1234'

def found = map.find { it.toString().contains(code) } as Boolean
assert found

def notFound = map.find { it.toString().contains('foo') } as Boolean
assert ! notFound
```

The cast works because of [Groovy Truth](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/08/groovy-goodness-tell-groovy-truth.html).